# how can i fetch data from two related tables into single variable laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

i have two tables first is clients and second one is relations.
in relations table i have two fields namely id and title.
my clients table contain field relation_id which is related to relations table id.
Now my question is that how can i fetch clients table data but instead of relation_id i want corresponding title which is in relations table in laravel.

Comment: do u use eloquent?

Comment: $clientdata = DB::table('clients')->get();

Comment: this type of query i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you already setup relations in your model you can simply use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) like this:

```
Client::with('your relation')->get();
```

or you can use [Join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins)

```
Client::leftJoin('table1', 'table2')->select('select columns that you want')->get();
```

leftJoin is a little bit hard if you have no clue what is join/leftJoin/RightJoin or innerjoin

Here is another example from laravel doc which is more suitable for your case

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->get();
```

**Edit:
Based on what you provided here your query should be something like this:**

```
$clientdata = DB::table('clients')->leftJoin('clients.id', '=' ,'relations.relation_id')->select('clients.*', 'relations.id as rel_id', 'relations.relation-title')->get();
```

Comment: in clients table i have three fields namely name, mobile and relation_id . relation_id is related to id of relations table, now i want to get all clients table information but instead of relation_id i want title from relations table, so please can you explain me it with code??

Comment: can i have tables names ?

Comment: two tables first is clients in which fields are name, mobile, and relation_id, and second table relations in which field id and relation-title

Comment: $clientdata = DB::table('clients')->leftJoin('clients.id', '=' ,'relations.relation_id')->select('clients.*', 'relations.id as rel_id', 'relations.relation-title')->get();                                                                                     this is not working in laravel.

Comment: Thats laravel syntax anyways, what error are you getting ?

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'clients.relation_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select `clients`.*, `relations`.`id` as `rel_id`, `relations`.`relation-title` from `clients` left join `clients`.`relation_id` on `=` = `relations`.`id`) ◀"

Comment: my mistake i guess please use this $clientdata = DB::table('clients')->leftJoin('clients.relation_id', '=' ,'relations.id')->select('clients.*', 'relations.id as rel_id', 'relations.relation-title')->get();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DB::Table('clients')
->leftjoin('relations', 'relations.id', '=', 'clients.relation_id')
->select('clients.*', 'relations.title')
->get();
```